# BottomSheetDialogFragment- Close only on full swipe Kotlin Android

Tags: android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet, android-event, android-gesture, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment to show list of items inside a fragment. Each list item got a click event mapped. The problem here is, most of the times click action turns into swipe down action and BottomSheetDialogFragment  is getting closed. I have no custom events to monitor the events in my code.

```
    dialog?.also {
      it.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)?.let { bottomSheet ->
         bottomSheet.layoutParams?.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
         BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
         BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).skipCollapsed = true
      }
   }
```

I have to prevent the close event of BottomSheetDialogFragment on click action which turns into swipe down action because of small extra movement added. This could happen and needs to handle since this application will be used by general public.

Can anyone suggest to find the swipe distance on BottomSheetDialogFragment. So that if the value is lower, the dialog will remain open. And if the value if high because of intentional swipe event, the dialog will get dismissed.